# How should I interpret my plot!

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation, two-way

I ran a two way anova to test effect of sex (2levels) and locations (3 levels) on size of fish. I got this results. First, I would like to know whether my interaction is synergistic or antagonistic as I had both increase and decrease. And should I interpret my results based on changes of male in three locations?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, for two positive main effects, an antagonistic interaction means a negative interaction coefficient (as one variable increases, the effect of the other is weakened), whereas a synergistic interaction means a positive interaction coefficient (as one variable increases, the effect of the other is strengthened).

These terms are for interactions of continuous variables; they don't apply at all in your situation as you appear to have two categorical variables (sex, and location). To interpret your interaction, you may want to use simple effects tests or posthoc comparisons. It looks like you're using SPSS from the style of your plot; [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21475404) and [here](http://www2.gsu.edu/~epstco/aeraStudent.pdf) are links to SPSS instructions for following up on a significant interaction with simple effects and post hoc tests.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, no one will be able to tell whether the interaction is "synergistic" or "antagonistic" because there is no information given what's behind the "Eastern", "Western" and "Inter-mountain" labels. Are these just different locations, representing different environments? Or are they somehow else different, e.g. pollution levels? Why are you interested in "synergistic" or "antagonistic" effects?

What I see here is that:

1. *There is no meaningful difference in female fish length across "Eastern", "Western" and "Inter-mountain".*
2. *Male fish are generally smaller, except for the "Western" category, which requires some explanation/speculation.*

So what I would try to figure out is why male fish in "Western" are much larger compared to the "Eastern" and "Inter-mountain" categories.

Comment: Yes these are locations that we taken our samples from. We are interested to investigate effect of sex and location on fish length.